# How can I use a single function for both Rows to calculate value?

Tags: javascript, html

When I enter some number on 4th input. It automatically calculates the value in last two inputs. I have used two separate functions for these separate row. how can I use a single function that works for both?

```js
function myFunction() {
 var b = document.getElementById('b').value;
 var d = document.getElementById('d').value;
    var e = document.getElementById("e").value;
    var f = document.getElementById('f').value = (d*e).toFixed(3);
 var g = document.getElementById('g').value = (f*b).toFixed(3);   
}

function myFunction1() {
 var b = document.getElementById('b1').value;
 var d = document.getElementById('d1').value;
    var e = document.getElementById("e1").value;
    var f = document.getElementById('f1').value = (d*e).toFixed(3);
 var g = document.getElementById('g1').value = (f*b).toFixed(3);   
}
```

```html
<table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td>Produto</td>
        <td style="display: none;"></td>
        <td>Diluição</td>
        <td>Necessario de produto para limpar 1m2</td>
        <td>Metragem do ambiente a ser limpo</td>
        <td>Resultado em litros de produto concentrado para limpar a metragem do cliente</td>
        <td colspan="2">Quantidade de solução  em litros</td> 
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="7" style="text-align: center;">CONCENTRADOS- LINHA CONC</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">Concentrax Desinfetante</td>
        <td><input id="b" type="text" name="" value="15" disabled></td>
        <td><input id="c" type="text" name="" value="1/15" disabled> </td>
        <td><input id="d" type="text" name="" value="0.011" disabled> </td>
        <td><input id="e" type="text" name="" value="0" oninput="myFunction()"></td>
        <td><input id="f" type="text" name="" value="0.00"></td>
        <td><input id="g" type="text" name="" value="0.00"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input id="b1" type="text" name="" value="200" disabled></td>
        <td><input id="c1" type="text" name="" value="1/200" disabled> </td>
        <td><input id="d1" type="text" name="" value="0.00083" disabled> </td>
        <td ><input id="e1" type="text" name="" value="0" oninput="myFunction1()"></td>
        <td><input id="f1" type="text" name="" value="0.00"></td>
        <td><input id="g1" type="text" name="" value="0.00"> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you open to using `jQuery` or do you want to accomplish this in `Vanilla Javascript` ?

Comment: yes, I don't want to use JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, if you want a scalable approach:

```
function myFunction(suffix) {
  var b = document.getElementById('b' + suffix).value;
  var d = document.getElementById('d' + suffix).value;
  var e = document.getElementById("e" + suffix).value;
  var f = document.getElementById('f' + suffix).value = (d*e).toFixed(3);
  var g = document.getElementById('g' + suffix).value = (f*b).toFixed(3);   
}
```

And then call it with myFunction('') for first row and myFunction('1') for second.

Comment: Great! that's what I was searching :) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(id) {
 if(id == "firstRow"){
    var b = document.getElementById('b').value;
    var d = document.getElementById('d').value;
    var e = document.getElementById("e").value;
    var f = document.getElementById('f').value = (d*e).toFixed(3);
    var g = document.getElementById('g').value = (f*b).toFixed(3);   
 }else if(id == "secondRow"){
    var b = document.getElementById('b1').value;
    var d = document.getElementById('d1').value;
    var e = document.getElementById("e1").value;
    var f = document.getElementById('f1').value = (d*e).toFixed(3);
    var g = document.getElementById('g1').value = (f*b).toFixed(3);   
 }
}
```

HTML

```
<tr>
    <td rowspan="3">Concentrax Desinfetante</td>
    <td><input id="b" type="text" name="" value="15" disabled></td>
    <td><input id="c" type="text" name="" value="1/15" disabled> </td>
    <td><input id="d" type="text" name="" value="0.011" disabled> </td>
    <td><input id="e" type="text" name="" value="0" oninput="myFunction('firstRow')"></td>
    <td><input id="f" type="text" name="" value="0.00"></td>
    <td><input id="g" type="text" name="" value="0.00"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input id="b1" type="text" name="" value="200" disabled></td>
    <td><input id="c1" type="text" name="" value="1/200" disabled> </td>
    <td><input id="d1" type="text" name="" value="0.00083" disabled> </td>
    <td ><input id="e1" type="text" name="" value="0" oninput="myFunction('secondRow')"></td>
    <td><input id="f1" type="text" name="" value="0.00"></td>
    <td><input id="g1" type="text" name="" value="0.00"> </td>
```

Working codepen

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dKwWvW

Comment: Great ! but in this way I have to repeat the code again and again by only changing the id, can we use the single code with a single function? is there any way we use id on <tr> and get the desired output for every row?

Comment: @RanaToqeerIqbal I really don't know what your requirements are from this program. Maybe if you can tell us how can we distinguish. Either you can send the suffix like the above answer suggests but it would still require you to create multiple table rows.


Other thing you can do is use backend language to create table rows according to your will and set and ID, or a suffix to send to the javascript function.

Comment: Please check the answer of @emilpalsson, that's what i am looking for.